# Racing balls question

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, simulations

My question is related to simulation of racing ball demonstration.
http://www.phy.ntnu.edu.tw/ntnujava/index.php?topic=142

One ball goes on a straight path, while another one goes on a curved path. On the simulation the second ball going on the blue part down hill which is parabola has a constant component of the velocity in the x direction. Why is that the case when the slope changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the entire curved part of the path the second ball has higher velocity in x direction than the other ball on the level path. On the curved part there is acceleration $a_{slope}=g\sin\theta$ where $\theta$ the slope angle to the horizontal. Acceleration in the x axis $a_x=a_{slope}\cos\theta$.  Velocity cannot be constant as long as there is a slope. Furthermore the rate of change in this velocity is also dependent on that slope angle.